# having a problem with c# form keydown event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `MaskedTextBox`, and I want it to do an event when I press `[Enter]`. It's working well, but when I press `[Enter]` the code calls the function twice and enters the `if` statement twice, affecting the result of the game. I want the code to enter the function once.

This is the code that generates the `MaskedTextBox`:

```
MaskedTextBox AnswerTextBox = new MaskedTextBox();

void DrawAnswerTextBox()
{
    AnswerTextBox.Location = new Point(371,186);
    AnswerTextBox.Size = new Size(395, 55);
    AnswerTextBox.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 25);
    AnswerTextBox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    AnswerTextBox.KeyDown += mtbEnterAnswer;            

    this.Controls.Add(AnswerTextBox);
}
```

This is the function that will be called in the `KeyDown` event:

```
private void mtbEnterAnswer(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MaskedTextBox maskedTextBox = (MaskedTextBox)sender;
        int.TryParse(maskedTextBox.Text, out int result);
        CheckAnswer(result);
    }
}
```

After the code finish the `CheckAnswer()` the code will back to the `if` statement and check the answer again and change the game info twice in row.

I tried preview key down like in the photo but that did not work.

Comment: You're attaching a *new* event handler every time you call `DrawAnswerTextBox`. You're also adding the same control multiple times to `Form.Controls`

Comment: The code you've posted works fine. The problem would arise if you call `DrawAnswerTextBox` more than once, in which case the event handler is connected more than once It will be called once for each time it's added to the control's `KeyDown` event.